# ASP.NET MVC iframe load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I load an ascx control in an ASP.NET MVC? I'm using `url.action` in src but it is not working. Can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ascx to appear in the response then you can use the `Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial` methods.

If you want to have an IFrame in the response that will load some other page, then you cannot use an ascx control alone. You will need a full view (aspx) that is returned from some action method. The full view could use `Html.Partial` and `Html.RenderPartial` to render your ascx.